# Parse span in div

Tags: android, jsoup

Hi I'm new in JSOUP and I need to retrieve a span value.
This is my html source:

```
  <div class=" exactCenterlabel" style="font-size: xx-large">
 <span id="labelfriends" style="display:inline-block;border-style:Outset;font-family:Guttman Yad-Brush;font-size:50pt;font-weight:bold;font-style:italic;height:115px;width:868px;margin-bottom: 0px">!תכיר מי הם החברים שלך </span> 
</div>
```

I have tried this `String value = doc.select("span#labelfriends").text();`

But it doesn't retrieve what I want. Can you help?

Comment: Check my answer if it's not work then post the full html source

Comment: this is my test website http://knowyourfriend.ddns.net/  icant post the full html source !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use This (Edited)
Use http://109.67.102.212:90/ as your url instead of http://knowyourfriend.ddns.net/ because it internally call http://109.67.102.212:90/ from frames

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://109.67.102.212:90/").timeout(10000)
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0")
                .get();
    System.out.println(doc.select("div.exactCenterlabel").select("span#labelfriends").text());
 }
```

Comment: post the full html source

Comment: and also try print the value with `System.out.println(doc.html());` and check is span tag with id=labelfriends inside div tag with class=exactCenterlabel contains in the output

Comment: NO it dosnt in the output